# Seperate logs for different jars in war file

Tags: java, log4j

I have a war file which is deployed on jboss server. This war contains some jar files. 
What i need is to create seperate logs for different jars.
I am using log4j for logging purpose and also intergrated log4j properties file in each jar.
My log4j for every jar have different paths.
Still the logs are generated in server.log of jboss.
I need help to generate seperate logs for every jar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make different log file for different jar, you  will  have to configure it in your   `log4j.properties` file related to every jar(I assume that every jar have different  package naming convention).

Here is an example like if you want to log message in different file  whose package name starts with `org.jar1` and `org.jar2`.

```
log4j.debug=true
log4j.logger.org.jar1=DEBUG,jar1logger
log4j.logger.org.jar2=DEBUG,jar2logger

log4j.additivity.org.jar1=false
log4j.additivity.org.jar2=false
log4j.appender.jar1logger=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.jar1logger.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.jar1logger.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t]<%-5p> %c -> %m%n
log4j.appender.jar1logger.File=/var/log/mylog/jar1.log
log4j.appender.jar1logger.Append=true
log4j.appender.jar1logger.MaxFileSize=1024KB
log4j.appender.jar1logger.MaxBackupIndex=5

log4j.appender.jar2logger=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.jar2logger.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.jar2logger.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t]<%-5p> %c -> %m%n
log4j.appender.jar2logger.File=/var/log/mylog/jar2.log
log4j.appender.jar2logger.Append=true
log4j.appender.jar2logger.MaxFileSize=1024KB
log4j.appender.jar2logger.MaxBackupIndex=5
```

Based on your requirement whether you want  to create log on daily basis or on size basis you have to change your configuration.

Keep in mind  if any jar whose package name in any jars start with `org.jar1`  then all logs        will be written into  `jar1.log` file.

Comment: Thanks @rajeev for your help. I tried as per your suggestion for somehow it didn't worked.

Comment: log4j.debug=true
log4j.logger.com.stgmastek.rbs.services.wrapper=DEBUG,jar1logger
#log4j.logger.org.jar2=DEBUG,jar2logger

log4j.additivity.com.stgmastek.rbs.services.wrapper=false
log4j.appender.jar1logger=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.jar1logger.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.jar1logger.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t]<%-5p> %c -> %m%n
log4j.appender.jar1logger.File=/data/jboss/BOP_TEMP/iso.log
log4j.appender.jar1logger.Append=true
log4j.appender.jar1logger.MaxFileSize=1024KB
log4j.appender.jar1logger.MaxBackupIndex=5

Comment: above is my log4j property file which is deployed in my jar file.Do i need to deploye this in my war file.Please help me if i am missing something.

Comment: yes  you need to deploy it. !. Make sure that your log4j.properties is available inside WEB-INF/classes directory.

Comment: Now i am using log4j.xml which is located at WEB-INF\classes\ . My jar is located at WEB-INF\lib\ . i am trying to access this file using my java code inside jar. i am using DOMConfigurator.configure(".WEB-INF\classes\/log4j.xml"); i am getting exception of FileNotFound.

Comment: servletContext.getResource("/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.xml") i hope this would work.

Comment: Hi rajeev. i am not using servlet here.i am reading this xml through my simple java class

Comment: On which framework  are you working ?  You have to use either relative path as you mentioned  or absolute path .

Comment: I have one jar which is inside war. in my war i have log4j.xml at WEB-INF\classes\log4j.xml. my jar is inside WEB-INF\lib\. From my java class inside my class(No servlet) i have to access log4j.xml for the logging purpose.DOMConfigurator.configure("/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.xml"); gives me nofilefound exception. How i can give absolute path.

Comment: @user2500313  there is only way to get relative path  for the deployed resource is  to use context.getResource("/WEB-INF/youpath") or context.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/yourpath").

Comment: After some analysis i found the issue that my jar itself conatins WEB-INF folder and my class is searching for log4j.xml in its own WEB-INF folder but the log4j.xml is present at WEB-INF folder of war file. is there any way to get the WEB-INF path of war not the jar