# Generate library (.jar) to generate a standard Log

Tags: java, log4j

I have a maven project (X.war), with spring 3.2 (is a Legacy project) log4j v1.2.17, and I was create a library for generate a standard log (fooLog.jar) with log4j v1.2.7 and import fooLog.jar into X.war (with maven obviously).  The problem is, the foo.jar library setting (log4j) take the Log4j configuration of the X.war

This fooLog.jar I need integrate with many other projects, I saw this solution [Seperate logs for different jars in war file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28959108/seperate-logs-for-different-jars-in-war-file) but it does not convince me if it is the best solution for what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When writing a library, you should generally rely on a logging facade like `commons-logging` or `SLF4J`, then configure the specific logging implementation in each place you'll use it (eg `Log4J` for the WAR project).

If it's only for internal use, you can probably get away with using Log4J directly, just not supplying a configuration file when creating the JAR. For unit testing the JAR project, assuming that also uses Maven, you can put Log4J configuration in `src/test/resources`, which won't be packaged.